# What's the difference between these two ways of creating a C++ class?

Tags: c++

I don't know how to name these things properly. I want to create a class, declare and define it's constructor with a variable and default value. I figured out that both these ways work. But what's the difference? Is one of them correct or both are good?

```
class Box
{
   public:
   int size;
      Box() {size = 6;};
};


class Box
{
   public:
   int size;
      Box(): size(6) {};
};
```

Comment: The 2nd should be prefered.

Comment: Is there a reason why (like performance or something)? Or it's just convention?

Comment: Mostly performance, also there are contexts that the initializers list is mandatory (e.g., initialization of references, const variables e.t.c)

Answer (score 1):

There is little difference, for `int`, but for complex classes, the initializer list is better.

Consider `const int`, `int &`, which show the syntactic benefit